# Jquery Slide effect on absolut positioned Div

Tags: jquery, html, css-position, slidetoggle

I am having some trouble using the slide effect (slideToggle, in this case) on some `position:absolute` `Divs`.

Before I've done the `position` work - I needed it for the border arrow - it worked perfectely. But, after I use `position:absolute` on `divs` the effect doens't work anymore. So, I believe it has something to do with the effect being made where the `Div` doesn't exist?

**My HTML:**

```
<div style="width: 200px; border-width: 1px; border: dotted" onclick="clickDiv();">
    click me
</div>
<div id="DivTeste">
    <div class="chat-bubble-arrow-border"></div>
    <div class="chat-bubble-arrow"></div>
    <div class="teste box">
        <p>e</p>
        <p>e</p>
        <p>e</p>
        <p>e</p>
        <p>e</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**My CSS:**

```
.box {
   overflow: auto;
   display: block;
   height:100px;
   width: 200px;
   border-width: 1px;
   border: solid;
   top: 50px;
   position:absolute;
}

.chat-bubble-arrow-border {
   border-color: transparent transparent #000 transparent;
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 10px;
   height:0;
   width:0;
   position:absolute;
   top: 30px;
   left:30px;
}


.chat-bubble-arrow {
   border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 10px;
   height: 0;
   width: 0;
   position: absolute;
   left: 30px;
   top: 33px;
   z-index: 100;
}
```

And my JS:

```
$(function () {
   $('#DivTeste').hide();
});

function clickDiv() {
   $('#DivTeste').slideToggle();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just teaked the code and made it work with relative position.

Changed this two from class box:

```
   top: 16px;
   position: relative;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sanman/4xsZM/

Why don't you use something like [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/demos/) for what it seems that you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

check out the solution i tried for you. slightly amended your coding anyway but nothing major.

`click here for JS Fiddle`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#click').click(function(){
        $('#DivTeste').slideToggle(500);
    })
});
```

```css
.box {
   overflow: auto;
   display: block;
   height:100px;
   width: 200px;
   border-width: 1px;
   border: solid;
   top: 50px;
   position:absolute;
}

#DivTeste{
display:none;
}

.chat-bubble-arrow-border {
   border-color: transparent transparent #000 transparent;
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 10px;
   height:0;
   width:0;
   position:absolute;
   top: 30px;
   left:30px;
}


.chat-bubble-arrow {
   border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 10px;
   height: 0;
   width: 0;
   position: absolute;
   left: 30px;
   top: 33px;
   z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="click" style="width: 200px; border-width: 1px; border: dotted; cursor:pointer">
    click me
</div>
<div id="DivTeste">
    <div class="chat-bubble-arrow-border"></div>
    <div class="chat-bubble-arrow"></div>
    <div class="teste box">
        <p>e</p>
        <p>e</p>
        <p>e</p>
        <p>e</p>
        <p>e</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Looks like the problem is still there! The hidden div appears and disappears on click, but without the sliding effect as it should be. That's the problem, and that only appeared after absolut positioning the Divs. Thank you, anyway!